# JSF holds the values in components in different users

Tags: spring, jsf, jsf-2

I'm new in JSF, and I'm trying to use JSF 2 and Richfaces + Spring (3.2.3) + Hibernate (3.6). The application server is JBoss 7.1. The problem is when I deploy my application and use it in my computer it works well, but when I use it in another computer in my LAN or other browser in my same computer, all the values stored in the first use are set in all the fields. I have to say that the application works well but it seems that one user is using it even if I use it in different computers at the same time.

I also deployed it in Cloudbees but it has the same problem through internet.

PD. I searched other similar questions but I couldn't find an answer.

My login.xhtml:

```
<h:form>                
            <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                <h:outputLabel value="Usuario "/>
                <h:inputText id="txt_usuario" value="#{login.usuario}" required="true" requiredMessage="Debe ingresar su usuario."/><br/>
                <h:message for="txt_usuario" />

                <h:outputLabel value="Password "/>
                <h:inputSecret id="pwd_password" value="#{login.password}" required="true" requiredMessage="Debe ingresar su password."/><br/>
                <h:message for="pwd_password" />
            </h:panelGrid>
            <h:commandButton value="Login" action="#{login.iniciarSesion()}"/>
        </h:form>
```

---

```
package com.ejemplo.app.controller;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.ejb.PostActivate;
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import com.ejemplo.app.entidades.Usuario;
import com.ejemplo.app.service.UsuarioService;
import com.ejemplo.app.util.Constantes;

@Component("login")
@ManagedBean(name = "login")
@SessionScoped
public class LoginController {

    @Autowired
    private UsuarioService usuarioService;

    private String usuario;
    private String password;

    public LoginController() {

    }

    public String iniciarSesion() {
        try {
            Usuario login = usuarioService.validarIngreso(usuario, password);

            FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
            facesContext.getApplication().createValueBinding("#{sessionScope.user}").setValue(facesContext, login);

            if(login.getTipo().equalsIgnoreCase(Constantes.CARGO_RESIDENTE))
                return "residente/home";
            else if(login.getTipo().equalsIgnoreCase(Constantes.CARGO_LOGISTICA))
                return "logistica/home";
            else if(login.getTipo().equalsIgnoreCase(Constantes.CARGO_ADMINISTRADOR))
                return "administrador/home";
            else
                System.err.println("Usuario no encontrado.");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
            facesContext.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Usuario no encontrado.", "Descripcion del mensaje."));
        }       
        return "solicitud_materiales";      
    }

    public String getUsuario() {
        return usuario;
    }
    public void setUsuario(String usuario) {
        this.usuario = usuario;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't understand your question, but `@RequestScoped` should be sufficient for a login form...

Comment: It works, but I try to use it in two computers at the same time. I login in the first computer, then I go to other and when I want to use it, the value in the usuario field is already set with the value that I wrote in the first computer. The same happens if I want to use it in two different browsers. And if I login in the second computer it overwrites the value in the other computer. Because of this I can't have different users.

Comment: That behavior should not occure, you should get a separate session for every browser / every computer. The login form doesn't need to be `@SessionScoped`, but it doesn't explain the problem. Sorry, can't help much on that!

Comment: I think the same. Maybe the SessionScoped or ManagedBean annotation acts similar than a Stateful Bean in EJB but I never used it, I just read about it, I don't know if that could be true.

Comment: You're mixing up a bunch of stuff here that's going to make your troubleshooting all that much more difficult: the JSF `@ManagedBean` will not have `usuarioService` because Spring will not autowire into beans that are not in its context. What this leaves you with is `LoginController ` existing in 2 different contexts: Spring and JSF

Comment: I could solve it by adding this line on the name of the class. @Scope(proxyMode=ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS, value="session")
I found it in another post but I don't remember it.